# In a separable metric space, show that convergence in measure implies a sub sequence converges a.e

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(Y,d)$ be a separable metric space and $f_1, f_2, \cdots$ be measurable maps $X \to Y$, and $f_n \to f$ in measure. Show that there is $f_{n_k}$ a sub sequence such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e.

My attempt:

Let $f_n \to f$ in measure. We can now take an increasing sequence of mappings, call them $E_i$, where $\mu(E_N)< \infty \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we can take a sub sequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $\mu(E_k\cap(d(f,f_{n_k})>\frac{1}{k}))<\frac{1}{2^k}$.

$\implies \forall N\in \mathbb{N}$   $ \mu(E_N\cap(d(f,f_{n_k})>\frac{1}{k})) \leq N\mu(E_N) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} < \infty$.

My questions are:

1.) Is this along the right track?

2.) How would I guarantee convergence a.e?

3.) How to use the separability condition?

Thank you very much.